# open another webview on clicking on ad image

Tags: android, webview

I'm developing an app in which i have to display an ad,have set it's position and ad is displying but when we click on ad image this open in same webview.But i wanna when we click another webbview should open for display.Can any please help me out.Thanks

**Code:**

```
WebView ad = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
ad.loadUrl(url);
ad.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    // show the web page in webview but not in web browser
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: have look my code @NiravRanpara

Comment: Come here > http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20674/android-india

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally done this using.......following code

```
private class MyClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch second and third line, I think the problem is you are loading url prior to setting your webviewclient:

```
 WebView ad = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
 ad.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
 ad.loadUrl(url);

 class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
   @Override
    // show the web page in webview but not in web browser
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        getApplicationContext().startActivity(
        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
            return true;
     }
  }
```

Comment: Try to copy paste code from my answer and let me know if it worked

Comment: throwing error android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Comment: Did you put  class MyWebViewClient  as INNER class in your activity ? Try also view.loadUrl(url);

Comment: yeah doing that but same issue

Comment: And when you add view.loadUrl(url) in shouldOverrideUrlLoading ?

Answer (score 0):

I recognize that, when you comment out your `ad.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());`, the banner ad in the webview does start a new view.

I use only wrap the `img` tag with an anchor tag, that totally works in my development with Android 4.4